# c++ tracking discrete space sequence

Tags: c++, boost, intervals

I have a discrete space (say integers). They are split in groups say:

```
group A: 1, 4, 6
group B: 2, 3, 5
etc
```

Where the items in the group are in order and there is no repeating numbers between the groups.

I have a handler that pools every group for new items, where there might be zero or more new items.

Say:

```
pool Group A - returns 1, 4
pool Group B - returns 2, 3
pool Group A - returns 6
pool Group B - returns 5
```

The process of adding new items to the groups and pooling them is continuous.

I need to be able to tell at any point is there a hole in the discrete space that was already handled.

In this example when I handle 1 - the result is no - no hole. Then as soon I handle 4, this creates a hole between 1 and 4. Then Adding 2, there is still hole, but when I add 3 there is no hole anymore.

I am considering using boost::interval where I just add every item when it occurs. Seems extremely easy to implement, but boost interval is optimized for intervals. I do not like using std::vector or boost::dynamic_bitset, because there is no reason for me to keep increasing the memory footprint of the tracking. I do not need which numbers were handled - all I need is to be able to tell is there a hole or not.

The performance requirement is high. I am curious is there a better way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: "need to be able to tell at any point is there a hole in the discrete space that was already handled." - that' s not clear to me. Can you _show_ what you want to do? Boost ICL can be used for bitmaps quite effectively (see [Large Bitset](http://tinyurl.com/q8j7dto) sample), but I get the impression you're really after something of a "sliding window". Unless you provide enough information to determine how we could exploit that, I don't think we can help. At this moment your question is basically "The performance requirement is high" (the stock response is: `void foo() { }` is pretty fast :))

Comment: it say that the stream is offline. It will be curious to see, I assume you could add link to the recording with your answer

Comment: Let me know if you couldn't connect to the stream. Meanwhile, my answer is complete. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use Boost ICL, as you suspected.

The *default* interval combining style is "Joining". This is exactly what you need! So, it's home run.

Here's a trivial demo with exactly the input events as given in the example. I print the state of the record at each event (yay for Boost ICL IO support!).

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/438eb23e7a690a2e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/icl/interval_set.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using Set      = boost::icl::interval_set<int>;
using Interval = Set::interval_type;

int main() {

    Set record;

    // pool Group A - returns 1, 4
    // pool Group B - returns 2, 3
    // pool Group A - returns 6
    // pool Group B - returns 5

    int stepcount = 0;

    for (int sample : {
            1, 4,
            2, 3,
            6,
            5 })
    {
        record.insert(sample);
        std::cout << "state at #" << ++stepcount << ": " << record << "\n";
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
state at #1: {[1,1]}
state at #2: {[1,1][4,4]}
state at #3: {[1,2][4,4]}
state at #4: {[1,4]}
state at #5: {[1,4][6,6]}
state at #6: {[1,6]}
```

As you can see, the gap did indeed disappear right when 3 closed it. This seems to be exactly what you  want/described.

> **Note** You'll be happy to know that if holes are rare/big (contiguous ranges are "holes") then ICL will even get you highly compressed storage representation. That's in the core of the library features. So, profile things, I think you'll be fine with this.

If you need better scalability you can perhaps choose to truncate the "history" that you don't need anymore as the number go up. You'd do

```
record.erase(Interval::open(0, 4));
std::cout << "state after erase: " << record << "\n";
```

Which would print

```
state after erase: {[4,6]}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I am having another algorithm to determine if there is a hole when it becomes safe to ignore it. At this point I will remove the range(s) before it.

Comment: Good thinking. I just simplified the answer. On second look, the closed single samples also worked (and arguably less verbose than using half-open intervals). Discrete ranges are a bit confusing sometimes. Cheers.

Comment: By the way, the livecoding stream is still available here: https://www.livecoding.tv/video/a-bit-of-boost-graph-interval-containers/ around the 35:00 mark